# Problems adding image textures to "Extra Objects."

Tags: texturing

[image: These two objects have the same image texture]

These two objects both have the exact same image texture/node chain. I got this result from Material Properties > Base Color > Image Texture > Open File... then going into the Shader screen and adding a Vector > Displacement Node.

On the default square, everything works fine, but when I do the exact same thing on one of the "Extra Objects," for example this gear, it fails. Sometimes the failure is total like it is here... and sometimes part of the Extra Object will successfully hold the Image Texture and part of it will just be grey like the gear in that screenshot.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Surely this isn't the way Extra Objects are supposed to work - they have "Brilliant Diamonds" as one of the shapes... those aren't supposed to be blank grey.

I'm using Blender 2.90.1.

Comment: Extra objects (I don't know if all or some of them) have no UV map. You probably need to make one here (or change the material so that it does not use UVs).

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't know about the missing UV maps on these, so thanks for the tip.

Comment: Just in case someone has this same issue, that worked. I used a very dirty, ham-handed, nooby fix, but it held up: in the UV Editing workspace, I clicked the "UV" tab, then selected "Smart UV Project." That gave me a rudimentary UV map on my texture, which was good enough. There's probably a much better way to do it, but I'm only a yellow belt in Blender. I have to take whatever wins I can get. Thanks again for the help